# Huffman Coding using min priority queue

Tags: c++, huffman-code

In this Question, I need to print the huffman code for all the data. But for the given test case below, I'm getting different output.

**Input**

8

i j k l m n o p

5 9 12 13 16 45 55 70

Where

First line enters the number of letters

Second line enters the letters

Third line enters the frequencies of the letters

**Expected Output**

n: 00

k: 0100

l: 0101

i: 01100

j: 01101

m: 0111

o: 10

p: 11

**My Output**

n: 00

o: 01

k: 1000

l: 1001

i: 10100

j: 10101

m: 1011

p: 11

**My code**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    char data;
    int freq;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(char x, int y): data(x), freq(y), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

struct compare {
    bool operator()(Node *l, Node*r) {
        return l->freq > r->freq;
    }
};

void display(Node *p, string str) {
    if(p) {
        if(p->data != '$')
            cout << p->data << ": " << str << "\n";
        display(p->left, str + "0");
        display(p->right, str + "1");
    }
}

void huffmanCodes(char data[], int fr[], int n) {
    priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, compare > pq;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        pq.push(new Node(data[i], fr[i]));
    while(pq.size() != 1) {
        Node *l = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        Node *r = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        Node *t = new Node('$', l->freq + r->freq);
        t->left = l;
        t->right = r; 
        pq.push(t);
    }
    display(pq.top(), "");
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char data[n];
    int freq[n];
    for(auto &x: data) cin >> x;
    for(auto &x: freq) cin >> x;
    huffmanCodes(data, freq, n);
}
```

Comment: I didn't look at your code, but I note that if you swap the first two digits, you get the expected sequence. It may help finding the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add to 500's correct answer, depending on the choice made, you can get either of these trees, both of which are valid and optimal:

[image: two binary trees with slightly different topologies]

By the way, since you also show bit assignments, for *each* of those two trees there are 128 ways to assign codes to the symbols. You can make each branch individually 0 on the left and 1 on the right, or 1 on the left and 0 on the right. So there are actually 256 different ways to make valid Huffman codes for those frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't necessarily just one correct Huffman tree for a particular set of frequencies. If we look at yours, we initially have the following distribution

`i:5 j:9 k:12 l:13 m:16 n:45 o:55 p:70`

Combining the two smallest we get (ordered by frequency)

`(ij):14 m:16 (kl):25 n:45 o:55 p:70`

then again, combining the two smallest we get

`(kl):25 (ij)(m):30 o:55 p:70`

then after that, we get

`n:45 (kl)((ij)(m)):55 o:55 p:70`

Now here we have two entries with the same frequency (55), so we can combine `n` with either `(kl)((ij)(m))` or `o` to form a new node - both will yield valid Huffman trees, both guaranteed to be optimal in terms of code size, so we can pick either one, and details of how the priority queue is implemented will determine which one actually gets picked in your case.

As long as the same strategy is used both for the encoder and decoder, this will work fine either way.

Comment: The "strategy" comment doesn't quite make sense. The encoder needs to transmit the code to the decoder somehow. That is never sent as a list of frequencies, so there is no Huffman algorithm running on the decoder end that could use the same strategy.

Comment: @MarkAdler: Well, commercial implementations invariably use canonical encoding, passing just the lengths, of course, but conceivably you _could_ pass the frequencies.

Comment: As it happens for this example, canonical coding would result in exactly the same code. So no ambiguity. There are however examples where the resolution of ties in Huffman coding can result in different sets of code lengths.